# MUI DataGrid layout issues using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datagrid

Been trying to get MUI DataGrid to work for a few hours now, but for some reason the styling is placing the pagination information at the top of the table, on top of the column headers.
Maybe its something stupid I'm doing.  I have tried a really simple version to illustrate my issues.  Hope someone can please help me.  BTW I use v5+ of MUI and DataGrid.  React is v17+

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridRowModel } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import { GridColDef } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
export const DataGridTest: FC = () => {
  const paginationSize = 20;

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: "username", headerName: "Username", flex: 1, sortable: false, filterable: false },
    { field: "first_name", headerName: "First Name", flex: 1, sortable: false, filterable: false },
    { field: "last_name", headerName: "Last Name", flex: 1, sortable: false, filterable: false },
    { field: "email", headerName: "Email", flex: 1, sortable: false, filterable: false },
    { field: "phone", headerName: "Phone", flex: 1, sortable: false, filterable: false },
  ];

  const rows: GridRowModel[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      username: "Tony",
      first_name: "Tony",
      last_name: "Ballony",
      email: "Tony@test.com",
      phone: "0754512222",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      username: "Joe",
      first_name: "Joeseph",
      last_name: "Willson",
      email: "joe@test.com",
      phone: "0754512333",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={paginationSize} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The output looks like this.

[image]

So you can see that the pagination section that should be shown below the table data is instead positioned at the top of the page.  In fact the border that should be around the data is also moved to the top. I hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the height of `DataGrid`, like:

```
//// Your code ////

  return (
    <div>
      <DataGrid
          style={{ height: "700px" }}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={paginationSize} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can use stylesheets instead of inline styles ofc. It's just an example.

Comment: I will try that today and let you know. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks it did fix my problem.  But its a little dissapointing that the height isnt reactive, based on the number of rows displayed.

Comment: @RollingInTheDeep I'm glad I helped you. Could you accept my answer as well, I'm fighting with my friend for reputation.